# How to log in to my website account seperatly from facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website with facebook login button each time I login to my facebook it logs me in automatically to my website account. How Can I make the login process separate for each one I mean If I log to my facebook not necessarily to log in to my website account and vise versa.

This is the function that I call when anybody click on my facebook login button :

```
function facebook()
{
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user)
    {
        $params = array( 'next' => 'http://www.example.com/index.php' );
        $getLogoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.
        try 
        {
            $userdata = $facebook->api('/me');
        } 
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
        $_SESSION['facebook']=$_SESSION;
        $_SESSION['userdata'] = $userdata;
        $_SESSION['logout'] = $logoutUrl;

        $facebook=$_SESSION['facebook'];
        $userdata=$_SESSION['userdata'];
        $logoutUrl=$_SESSION['logout'];
        //Facebook Access Token
        $access_token_title='fb_'.$facebook_appid.'_access_token';
        $access_token=$facebook[$access_token_title];
        if(!empty($userdata))
        {
            $facebook_id=$userdata['id'];
            $name=$userdata['name'];
            $first_name=$userdata['first_name'];
            $last_name=$userdata['last_name'];
            $email=$userdata['email'];
            $is_fb_id_there = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE facebook_id = $facebook_id") or $GLOBALS['db']->raise_error();
            $rows = $GLOBALS['db']->num_rows($is_fb_id_there);
            if(empty($rows))
            {
                $GLOBALS['db']->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`facebook_id`, `username`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES($facebook_id,'$name','$email', '$first_name', '$last_name')");
                $users = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE facebook_id = $facebook_id") or $GLOBALS['db']->raise_error();  
                while($users_sql = $GLOBALS['db']->fetch_array($users))
                {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $users_sql['username'];
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $users_sql['id'];
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'true';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                while($users_sql = $GLOBALS['db']->fetch_array($is_fb_id_there))
                {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $users_sql['username'];
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $users_sql['id'];
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'true';
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
        //Redirecting to home.php
        header("Location: http://www.example.com");         
    }
    else
    { 

        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
         'scope' => 'email,user_birthday',
         'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.example.com/index.php'
        ));

        echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img  style="float:right;width:157px; height:22px; border:0;" src="../include-images/fb_giris.png"></a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken that's how oAuth works.

Comment: I know but is there anyway to do it separately for each application I mean not login for all / logout for all

Comment: Do you have any other code that checks authentication? The code above is when someone clicks the button, is there any automatic cookie/auth validation?

Comment: no there is no other code I use this just and after that I check the `$_SESSION['logged_in']` to see if the user logged or not and then call his session variables that I saved them in this function